# How to enable right click button for mousepad on Dell inspiron 13 with Ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: dell, 18.04, mousepad

I have recently installed `Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic Beaver` (development branch) on a Dell Inspiron 13 5000 series.

The actual problem I'm facing is that the right click button for the mousepad is not detected and there is no way to configure it. **I'm looking for the right button (below the mousepad area) to work, not having an area in the mousepad that simulates right click, nor wanting to use two fingers tap as right click**.

The mouspad has a button for right click which should work, but instead I'm having to use two fingers tap for tight click instead.

Of course if I use an USB mouse attached I can right click but I would like to have same right button click on the mousepad.

Actually I have following pointer output for `xinput`:

```
$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Logitech USB Receiver                     id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DELL0740:00 06CB:7E7E Touchpad            id=12   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ELAN Touchscreen                          id=11   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

I had same problem while installing `PCLinux` and `Slackware` so I am thinking of drivers issue maybe. But not sure how to tackle this.

How can I enable the right button click on the mousepad? Means I want the physical button on the mousepad to work properly.

Comment: What you see is intended in 18.04. Tap the touchpad with 2 fingers and you will get the context menu.

Comment: As I stated in my question I don't want to need to use my two fingers tap to emulate right button click. This laptop has a mouse pad with two buttons and I believe the right button click should work to show context menu, but I found no way till now for this to happen.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right Click not working on ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029444/right-click-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: This is not a duplicate. The mentioned question by @GonzaloMatheu states the touchpad has no buttons, whereas my question states the touchpad has buttons, and I'm willing for right button on touchpad to work properly.

Comment: @Fabby the question you refer to mentions on how to simulate right button click with the touchpad area. This is not what I intend to do. The issue I have is that I have two buttons below the mousepad, one for left click and the other for right click. The left button works properly, whereas the right button is not working as expected. This isn't a duplicate I think.

Comment: What happens if you choose to switch the functionality of the two buttons? If the right click is working as left, then the button itself is detected, so maybe it is not a driver problem.

Comment: **Sorry!** Close vote retracted!  **:-)**

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: Install the `gnome-tweak-tool`

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Step 2: Open the  "gnome-tweak-tool"  by writing "gnome-tweak-tool" or simply "tweaks" in the Activities menu and navigate to the tab "Keyboard and Mouse".
 There go to the tab "Mouse Click Emulation" and choose one of the options "Fingers" or "Area".

Probably you want the "Area" option

Comment: OP's problem is with the physical right touchpad button. He wants the button to work. This does not answer that question.

Comment: @user68186 yet it is what he wants ;)

Comment: I can verify that selecting 'Area' works. It did for me anyway, I also have a Dell Inspiron 13 running Ubuntu 18.04