# Right click not working on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: touchpad, hp, 18.04

I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on my HP Pavilion series laptop. After installing this version of Ubuntu, right click is not working of my touchpad. How can I solve this? 
BTW: [This question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028776/no-secondary-button-right-click-on-touchpad?noredirect=1&lq=1) does not have any solution which which is working for me.
PS:- Problem remains after selection area in **gnome-tweak-tool**

Comment: See if this helps: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028776/no-secondary-button-right-click-on-touchpad

Comment: Would you be so kind as to expand your question with further detail? I see that the called duplicate didn't have any solutions that worked for you, but what I can't see is exactly what happened for each of the 2 solutions in the accepted answer that you tried. Thank your for helping us help you!

Comment: I have the same problem, and I followed the tutorial on this website and proved successful
https://www.siskom.xyz/2018/05/how-to-fix-touchpad-right-click-not-working-on-ubuntu-1804.html

Comment: I have the same problem on a system76 computer. tweaks has an option that doesn't seem to work for me when selected and I'd rather have both behaviors instead of choosing one or the other. any other ideas?

Comment: so the tweaks works I needed to log out and log in again for the effect to work. But I'd really rather have both options on at the same time is there any way to do that?

Comment: linux is so great lol

Comment: `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method areas` or check https://medium.com/p/40037ff249e1/responses/show

Answer (score 130, accepted):

> For instance, to right-click method on touchpads without a physical
>   button you need to perform a two-finger click (just tap anywhere with
>   two fingers). Clicking in the bottom right area of the touchpad no
>   longer works.
>
> If you don’t like this behaviour — and there’s a fair chance you might
>   not — you can use the Tweaks app (see step #5) to change the setting.

Source: [OMG Ubuntu](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/04/things-to-do-after-installing-ubuntu-18-04)  (see link for how to fix it)

Comment: It's mot working

Comment: @SamiulSk it won't work if you have installed the Synaptics driver.

Comment: stuff like this really needs to be highlighted in the changelog

Comment: Urgh, why is it only one or the other?  It has been both for years (forever?) and I tend to mix them up.  Being able to select only one is a PITA.

Comment: I take it back - the multi click emulation still works even when I switch back to using click emulation, so I still have both :)

Comment: It works, but it's not reliable.

Comment: two finger feature is awesome. Is it new feature in 18.04 or it was before also?

Comment: woow!!! I thought my update is corrupt but this is awesome I love ubuntu

Comment: Even though I have a physical mouse button it was not working. However, selecting Area mouse click emulation in Gnome Tweaks solved the issue. The physical button now works as right clicking.

Comment: Thank you @OrganicMarble It was a great relief. I liked this new feature though this change would have been highlighted while installation.

Comment: We can also use this: gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.peripherals.touchpad click-method areas

Comment: wow, changes like this are really annoying ! All personal computers come with two buttons in the touchpad ?!  Persons that made this decision were like : It's stable and working perfectly, let's complicate it .

Comment: Valid still in 23.04.  Was driving me nuts...

Answer (score 43):

I too had this issue with an HP Omen.. I downloaded the gnome tweaks and it fixed the problem.

Open Ubuntu software (orange briefcase) and type in the search "gnome tweaks".. launch the program and under keyboard and mouse tab>Mouse click emulation> choose AREA..click bottom right.....

Log out and re-login if the change didn't take effect right away.

[image: screen shot]

Comment: Which problem did it fix? Did it switch from two-finger tap to bottom-right click or enable both?

Comment: Randy.. for me it fixed the R click on my touchpad (there are no R or L buttons on the touchpad). At the bottom of Gnome Tweaks, it has "Area" section that I clicked on (put a check mark to enable). And now the touchpad works as it should.

Comment: This works for me! upgrade from ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04, then right click of my laptop(ASUS ROG series) touchpad broken.

Comment: @Wr3nch3r There was no need of logout

Comment: This worked, but I did have to completely reboot. Restarting gnome-shell didn't apply the change.

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
sudo vi /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

add:

```
Section "InputClass"
  Identifier "libinput touchpad catchall"
  MatchIsTouchpad "on"
  MatchDevicePath "/dev/input/event*"
  Driver "libinput"
  Option "Tapping" "True"
  Option "NaturalScrolling" "True"
EndSection
```

Comment: if you're missing xorg.conf consider the following which works on ubuntu-based builds:
`sudo mkdir /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`;
`cd /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d`;
`sudo nano 01-input.conf`;
then copy/paste the Section configuration listed above