# Ubuntu Budgie - Desktop right click menu

Tags: menu, budgie, ubuntu-budgie

[image]

Is there a way I can add another app the the Ubuntu Budgie - Desktop right click menu the same way "Open Tilix Here" has been added?

Sorry it may be a real dumb question but I can't figure it out.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved that by installing `gnome-tweaks` and changing a configuration for touchpad there. Then I've uninstalled `gnome-tweaks` with all its dependencies.

Here is the explanation how to do it with gnome-tweaks: https://askubuntu.com/a/1029445