# Right-click on Dell Precision 5520 touchpad, with 18.04, not working

Tags: touchpad

After installing Ubuntu Bionic Beaver, the right-click button of the touchpad stopped working.

Any fixes?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try a two-fingered double-tap to get the right-click menu.  Works for me on Ubuntu 18.04 on Precision 5530.  See [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1029444/right-click-not-working-on-ubuntu-18-04?rq=1).